# How can I add additional parameter to URL when using form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

URL always has to be something like
`http://foofooexample.com/communities?search=keyword&language=&genre=`

As you see both `language` and `genre` have to be blank all the time.
`keyword` can be anything depending on what user typed for search.
So I coded just like this below.
However, it always takes me to
`http://foofooexample.com/communities?search=keyword`

`language=&genre=` is missing. How can I solve this?

```
<%= form_tag communities_path(:language => '' ,:genre => '' ), :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
        <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'search', params[:search], autocomplete_community_title_communities_path, :class =>'input', :placeholder => 'Keyword' %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have additional parameters is using a [hidden_field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag).

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'genre', nil %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'language', nil %>
```

Comment: Thanks. is it the only way to do though? I only can add the url parameter to it by my way only when it's link_to method?

Comment: It does add the parameters, take a look at the generated form. But the form is submitted to that url with the form fields as parameters, so the others arent' retained. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is however possible also with some js voodoo, but this is the most maintainable and easiest way.